# jQuery hide dynamically generated element by clicking on static element

Tags: jquery, binding, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been looking for an answer to this, but I haven't quite been able to find something on stackoverflow that specifically addresses this issue.

Essentially, I have some radio elements that are dynamically generated by jQuery (although after the page has loaded—they get loaded when text is entered into an input field), and I need to check these dynamically loaded radio elements on a `keyup` event.

If I were clicking on the dynamically loaded elements, I could just use the `live` function. However, I need to check these elements when a certain `keyup` event occurs while I'm focused inside a standard DOM element input field (i.e. not generated by jQuery).

Note that the keys array is just an associative array of keys with numerical keyCode values.

So, the following does not work:

```
$('#inputField').bind('keyup', function(k) {
  switch (k.keyCode) {
    case keys['up']:
      $('#dynamicallyGeneratedElement').attr('checked', true);
      break;
  }
});
```

Because the dynamically generated radio elements weren't there at DOM ready. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Can you please post the pertinent HTML you are working with and the jQuery code that generates the radio buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you say the following?

> Because the dynamically generated radio elements weren't there at DOM ready

This should not be a problem.  More likely your case is never triggered.  Here are some things to try:

1. Use [`k.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) instead of `k.keyCode`.
2. Put an `alert()` inside the case statement of your event handler to see if it is ever even getting triggered.  Something like:
   `alert("event.  Found " + $("#dynamicallyGeneratedElement").length + " elements");`

Those 2 things should help you debug the problem.

Comment: You're correct. There was something else interfering with my `keyup`s. I'm still using k.keyCode because it's going to be easier for my project teammates to use some semantic keyboard shortcut names I've created.

Answer (score 0):

When you are generating the dynamic content (through append or ajax call) you can create a callback function that then does the binding for you.

If you need help with the actual code you would actually have to show the code you are using to dynamically add the content.

Comment: `<li>` elements are being appended to an `<ul>` element. i.e. in brief: `$('#theUl').append('<li><input type='radio'>Something</li>');` I'm not sure how the binding would work, though, because I'm not actually binding anything to the generated element, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery delegate:

```
$('body').delegate('#inputField', 'keyup', function(k) {
  switch (k.keyCode) {
    case keys['up']:
      $('#dynamicallyGeneratedElement').attr('checked', true);
      break;
  }
});
```

The `$('body')` is an expensive selector, try with the direct parent container of the `#inputField` element. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Brandon that it shouldn't matter at all that your radio buttons didn't exist at DOM ready -- the only thing that matters is they exist when your function needs to interact with them.

A couple of things that might help:

1. As mentioned, `keyCode` tends to be a bit buggy, depending on what browser you're using. I usually go with this check:

   ```
      if(window.event) // (IE)
      {keynum = k.keyCode;}
      else if(k.which) // (other browsers)
      {keynum = k.which;}
   ```

   This way, you can be sure that no matter the environment, your variable is being assigned correctly.
2. Any reason you are using `switch`? If you're only testing the one condition, just use a simple if statement.
3. Use the jQuery method `inArray()` to test whether or not your keypress variable is in the keys['up'] array.
4. Lastly - not sure if this matters (don't think it does), but I prefer to use checked="checked" for radio buttons rather than checked="true". I think it works the same way, but switch it up in a pinch.

Comment: I'm developing for Safari only, and am building a large set of keyboard responses. I just put one in the code for brevity's sake.